# Second monitor's resolution not on maximum with micro HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I got a Samsung NP900X3A Ultrabook (http://www.samsung.com/de/support/model/NP900X3A-A01DE) with Intel® HD Graphics 3000 and an external Samsung SyncMaster SA450 24" screen.
I plug the external screen into the micro HDMI with a VGA adapter. My problem is, that I can only set up the screen to run with 1440x900 resolution. I installed drivers etc. but no change. Is there anything I can do to get the full resolution the screen is capable of? Do I need to buy a HDMI to Micro HDMI cable?

Comment: You will need to use an HDMI cable more then likely to get any higher resolution.  Have you verified your Ultrabook even supports a higher resolution then 1440x900?

Comment: The ultrabook itself has a 1366x768 screen. But I've seen x1024 resolutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramhound was right. The Micro HDMI to HDMI connector (from the MS Surface) fixed the issue with the resolution. I wonder why samsung doesnt offer such a connector.